# Reclassify rasters from raster dataset with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, reclassify, error-000732, raster-dataset

I have a raster dataset ("RDS_NFlows_3035") with several bands that I would like to reclassify to a single value and save in another raster dataset ("RDS_NFlows_reclass_3035").
When I run the script I get in the main workspace (daycentGDB) and not in the output raster dataset only one raster, called Reclass_RDS_1, correctly reclassified and I get also following error:

RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset E:\projects\INMAP\ArcGISProject\DAYCENT\DAYCENT.gdb\RDS_NFlows_3035\Reclass_RDS_1 does not exist or is not supported

I have no rasters in my input raster dataset with that name (Reclass_RDS_1), since this is the default name given to the output by the processing tool and I can't understand why the script looks for such a raster and why it saves it outside the output raster dataset.

```
NFlows_in_rds = os.path.join(daycentGDB, "RDS_NFlows_3035")
NFlows_out_rds = os.path.join(daycentGDB, "RDS_NFlows_reclass_3035")
arcpy.env.workspace = NFlows_in_rds
nflow_rs  = arcpy.ListRasters()
outRsSuff = "_reclass"
for rs in nflow_rs:
    print("Working on {}".format(rs))
    inRaster = Raster(rs)
    minVal = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRaster, "MINIMUM")
    maxVal = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRaster, "MAXIMUM")
    print("min: {}, max: {}".format(minVal, maxVal))
    remap = RemapRange([[minVal, maxVal, 999]])
    outRsName = "{}{}".format(rs, outRsSuff)
    print(outRsName)
    outRs = Reclassify(inRaster, "VALUE", remap)
    outRs.save(os.path.join(NFlows_out_rds, outRsName))
```

This is the structure of my GDB:

```
DAYCENT.gdb (File geoDB)  
    RDS_NFlows_3035 (Raster dataset)  
        mineralFertilization (Band 1 of raster dataset)  
        organicFertilization (Band 2 of raster dataset)  
        N2O (Band 3 of raster dataset)  
        N2 (Band 4 of raster dataset)
```

What I expect from script is a GDB like this:

```
DAYCENT.gdb
    RDS_NFlows_3035
        mineralFertilization
        organicFertilization
        N2O
        N2
    RDS_NFlows_reclass_3035
        mineralFertilization_reclass
        organicFertilization_reclass
        N2O_reclass
        N2_reclass
```

But after the script returns error, the GDB structure is:

```
DAYCENT.gdb
    RDS_NFlows_3035
        mineralFertilization
        organicFertilization
        N2O
        N2
    Reclass_RDS_1
        Band_1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your understanding of what a *Raster Dataset* is? I assume you have already created a Raster Dataset using the [Create Raster dataset tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-raster-dataset.htm)?

Read the first line of the usage section and it says:

> When you create a raster dataset, you are creating an empty location
> to contain a single raster dataset. You can then mosaic or load raster
> datasets into this location.

The key word here is LOAD. Your code is not loading into an empty existing Raster Dataset you are saving a Raster Dataset which is the output of a reclassification.

I think the confusion is coming from ESRI calling an empty raster a raster dataset and it appears you are trying to replicate the functionality of a *Feature dataset* which is a kind of folder in a Geodatabase.

I would simply create the raster from the reclass and then save it to:

```
E:\projects\INMAP\ArcGISProject\DAYCENT\DAYCENT.gdb\myNewRaster
```

Comment: The error is before I save or load the raster in raster dataset.
The error is here
`remap = RemapRange([[minVal, maxVal, 999]])`
This line creates a RDS with 1 band (called Band_1 with correct value 999) in this path "E:\projects\INMAP\ArcGISProject\DAYCENT\DAYCENT.gdb\Reclass_RDS_1". But 'Reclass_RDS_1' is the processing tool default name. It seems that the script creates this default RDS, does not assign the outRsName I set and does not iterate through bands in the input RDS after first cycle. I think that I didn't write correctly the iteration

Comment: Can you share your raster dataset ("RDS_NFlows_3035") with the several bands? It's difficult to identify the problem if we can't replicate it.

Comment: Sorry I can't since data are confidential for the moment. I've edited my question

Comment: I'm not sure how you load your rasters into an existing blank raster dataset (never done that) but may I suggest an alternative workflow, reclassify your individuals bands into separate rasters (think of 1 TIFF file for each band) then reconstruct your multi-band raster (now with the reclassified values) using the Composite Bands tool rather than trying to insert each band on each iteration of your loop?